# How can I do a clean reinstall from a bootable USB if I'm having my computer boot from it?

Tags: reinstall

Newbie here, trying to clean reinstall from USB. Not entirely sure what I did but either way want to start from scratch again. I have a bootable USB drive but can't seem to get my computer to boot into it?

When I installed Ubuntu I went for the full version, its on a laptop I don't use as my main computer and I couldn't stand windows 10!

As it stands I can't seem to get my laptop to boot using the USB (I'm guessing its quite easy but I'm missing something) currently getting a message about a package needing to be reinstalled but can't fond an archive, which has basically rendered the laptop unusable at the moment (apologies for any spelling mistakes using phone for all of this) any help would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: What do you mean by "full version"? Did it boot from the USB originally? What kind of laptop? Did it come from the store with Windows 10? Do you know if is UEFI or BIOS? Can you describe what went wrong?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu for about a month, went to install virtual box earlier and since then my laptop has been giving me the message I described in the question. I didn't partition my laptop I only have Ubuntu on it. I formated the USB using startup disk but it won't boot into the installer. I'm not sure if I should be holding down keys like with other systems in order to get it to work?

Comment: So a month ago you were able to boot from the USB, or did you install from a DVD? Are you going through the a temporary boot menu, selecting the USB, and it fails; or can you not get the system to select the USB in the first place?

Comment: Yes, first time round everything worked fine. Now the computer doesn't seem to recognise there is a USB there and is taking me straight to the password screen.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up booting into GRUB and reordering priorities so that the USB would boot first.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)